# How to set the first row of table colorful?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a table and I want to make its header row as gray color.
I have tried the below methode but it gives the whole table as gray color

```
 PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(4);
 table1.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 50f,80f,50f,330f });
 table1.TotalWidth = 800f;//table size
 table1.LockedWidth = true;

 table1.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
 table1.SpacingBefore = 5f;//both are used to mention the space from heading
 table1.SpacingAfter = 5f;
 table1.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
 table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table1.AddCell(new Phrase("NO", time515));
 table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Date & Day", time515));
 table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Hr", time515));
 table1.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Topics to be Covered", time515));
 Doc.add(table1);
```

Kindly see my expected output image
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options. If you just want to change the background color for a given row when needed you can just do that. The code below will write ten rows of four cells, the first row is gray and the remaining rows are blue.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        table1.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
    }
    else {
        table1.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLUE;
    }
    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("NO"));
    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Date & Day"));
    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Hr"));
    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Topics to be Covered"));
}
```

However, tables in iText actually support a more concrete idea of "Headers" and you declare these simply by telling the `PdfPTable` how many rows should be considered the "header":

```
table1.HeaderRows = 1;
```

What's neat about this is that if your table actually spans multiple pages then your header will automatically be re-drawn on the next page. However, using this method you also need to perform a little extra work. iText exposes and interface for you to implement called `IPdfPTableEvent` that has a single method called `TableLayout`. Below is a full working example of an implementation, see the code comments for more details:

```
private class MyTableEvent : IPdfPTableEvent {

    public void TableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {

        //Loop through each header row
        for( var row = 0; row < headerRows; row++ ){

            //Loop through each column in the current row
            //NOTE: For n columns there's actually n+1 entries in the widths array.
            for( var col = 0; col < widths[row].Length - 1; col++ ){

                //Get the various coordinates
                var llx = widths[row][col];
                var lly = heights[row];
                var urx = widths[row][col + 1];
                var ury = heights[row + 1];

                //Create a rectangle
                var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);

                //Set whatever properties you want on it
                rect.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.PINK;

                //Draw it to the background canvas
                canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS].Rectangle(rect);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

To use it you just bind an instance to your table object:

```
table1.TableEvent = new MyTableEvent();
```